# Shift + drag and drop using coordinates in canvas element in cypress?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, cypress

How can we  shift + drag and drop a element from part of canvas to another part of same canvas using coordinates in cypress?

I had tried:

```
cy.get('canvas').click({shift:true.release:false}).trigger('mousedown',100,100).trigger('mousemove',200,200).trigger('mouseup',200,200)
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
cy.get('canvas')
  .trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 16 })  // shift
  .trigger('mousedown', 100, 100)
  .wait(200)
  .trigger('mousemove', 150, 150)
  .wait(200)
  .trigger('mouseup')
  .trigger('keyup', { keyCode: 16 }) // shift
```

In my specific case, I had to add the `wait` between mouse actions because I feel like Cypress was "too fast" for canvas.